# Сomparison of texts among themselves for mismatch

Tags: python

I want to make it so that when entering one text, it checks with the second for mismatches and gives it to me

what I have now implemented does not work, because if 1 text is longer than the second, it simply stops working because the number of words is not the same

```
a = 'qwerty bla Bla new'
a = a.split()
b = 'Bla qwerty bla'
for i in b.split():
    if i not in a:
        print(i)
```

I want it to work both ways
So that you can compare a b and b a

Comment: There are many ways to do this, but I suggest a one-liner: `if len(a.split()) == len(b.split()):` if you want to check if the word count is the same. If you want to print the missing words in both the strings, then you'd have to simply copy-paste the for loop and change `a` to `b` and `b` to `a`.

Comment: Can you provide some output format you would like to get please?

Comment: @Avad >>>'''new'''

Answer (score 0):

If you want your program to work both ways: a -> b, b -> a. Get a union of set's difference.

```
a = 'qwerty bla Bla new'
b = 'Bla qwerty bla'
a_words = set(a.split( ))
b_words = set(b.split( ))
print((a_words.difference(b_words).union(b_words.difference(a_words))))
```

**Output**:

```
{'new'}
```

It will also work if you switch `a` and `b`.

Comment: Depending on the desired results, this solution may be incorrect if A) order of the words is important and B) if we care how many times each word appears in each sentence - i.e., if 'bla' appears in b 47 times, this solution will not find the 45 extra 'bla's

Comment: Yes, you're right. If it would be a problem in author's specific case that can be easily fixed by counting words before those are put into sets.